# Four vector manipulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I have started doing *Relativistic Quantum Mechanics* from *Greiner*.

I'm having difficulty understanding the following derivation for commutation relations (page 4):

$$[\hat{p}^\mu, x^\nu] = i\hbar[\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_\mu}},g^{\nu \sigma}x_\sigma]=$$
$$= i\hbar g^{\nu \sigma}\frac{\partial x_\sigma}{\partial x_\mu}=$$

now this is the part I don't understand, how did we got from last equation to next one:

$$=i\hbar g^{\nu \sigma}\delta^{\mu}_\sigma$$

Why is:
$$ \frac{\partial x_\sigma}{\partial x_\mu}= \delta^{\mu}_\sigma$$

where $$\delta^{\mu}_\nu = g^{\mu \sigma}g_{\sigma \nu}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a the statement that if I define functions $f_i$ of $n$ real variables $\mathbf x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ as
\begin{align}
  f_i(\mathbf x) = x_i
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(\mathbf x) = \delta_i^j
\end{align}
The expression you wrote is just a notational shorthand for this result.  Why is this equation true?  Well, the expression on the left hand side is zero if $i\neq j$, and one if $i=j$.  On the other hand, $\delta^i_j$ is the Kronecker delta which is *defined* to be zero if $i\neq j$ and one if $i=j$, therefore the left and right hand sides match.

How does this relate to your expression for the Kronecker delta that involves the metric?  Well, the object $g^{\mu\sigma}$ is *defined* to be the components of the inverse of the metric having components $g_{\sigma\nu}$, the mathematical expression for this definition is precisely that $g^{\mu\sigma} g_{\sigma\nu} = \delta^\mu_\nu$.

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to write the stuff about $g$ and the inverse and an identity is like a $\delta$. Too lazy too write more.

Comment: But I still don't get how are last two equations the same. Why is the partial derivative the same as the product of two metric tensors.

Comment: On the RHS, the first $g$ is the inverse of the second $g$, so when you multiply them you get the identity matrix. If you think about it, entry $i,j$ of the identity matrix is $\delta_{ij}$. The explains why the two $g$'s gives you $\delta_{ij}$. Josh explains why the derivative gives you $\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: @enedene I added a bit more basically in line with the comments that I just noticed.